# Perplexing style difference: Why is there space between the buttons in the first card and not the others?

Tags: css

https://coreui.io/demo/React_Demo/#/buttons/buttons

Why do the buttons in the 'Options' card have space between them and the rest of the cards do not?

The CSS is identical of the button's, and the container card

No-one in my office can find the cause.

I have moved the Options card to a different location in the DOM and that makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the HTML, not the CSS

The first 'Options' card has whitespace between the buttons and the rest do not.

```
<div class="card-body"><button class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button> <button class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button> <button class="btn btn-success">Success</button> <button class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button> <button class="btn btn-danger">Danger</button> <button class="btn btn-link">Link</button> </div>
```

Comment: Duh.  I should have looked at the source first. Thanks.

Comment: <CardBody>
                <Button color="primary">Primary</Button>{' '}
                <Button color="secondary">Secondary</Button>{' '}